# Use Notification.requestPermission on different browser versions as per it's implementation

Tags: javascript, function, push-notification, notifications, web-push

I have a problem where a function has its implementation changed in newer browsers. I want to call the function accordingly as per the implementation.

```
Notification.requestPermission().then(function (permission) {...})
```

This was called previously like,

```
Notification.requestPermission(callback);
```

I was calling the initial way and so in older browsers it is breaking as the promise is not returned in their implementation.

Comment: I think you should change your title to ask about the *specific* function you're interested in, rather then the generic one it is now.

Comment: Done @JonathonReinhart

Comment: This may help you solve your problem - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API

Comment: Not really, they have demonstrated using the deprecated method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a shot at this. It seems like you need to have a function fired conditionally with a flag.

```
// Outer function to prevent scope pollution
(function(){
    function thingThatINeed() {}
    // Flag to keep track of whether it is called.
    var isCalled = false;
    function conditionalCall(){
       if(!isCalled) {
           // if the conditionalCall function is called more than once, the 
           // needed function will still only be called once.
           thingThatINeed();
           isCalled = true;
       }
    }
    // Call requestPermission with the deprecated form
    var promise = Notification.requestPermission(conditionalCall);

    // if a promise is returned, then use the promise.
    if(promise){
        promise.then(conditionalCall);
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

We can make a wrapper for the old safari browser, force them to return a `Promise`:

```js
const notificationRequestPermission = () => {
  return new Promise(Notification.requestPermission);
};

// Usage
notificationRequestPermission().then(console.log)
```